# How to edit a map programmatically?

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, pgm, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Situation:
i am currently on Ubuntu, using ROS Melodic.
I work with a self built robot, that has a laser scanner.
With the `gmapping` package I create a map, that I save with the `map_server` package.
I get the mymap.pgm and the mymap.yaml file like expected.

**Question**:
How can I programatically edit the `.pgm` file to have borders? I want to take the path of the robot and use them to draw borders inside the file. Manually doing it with a photo editing program is not a solution (see background info).

**Background**:
I need to develop a mowing robot for outside purposes. I am *not* indoors with walls, and all sides of the map can be expected open, as the fences might not be detectable (small metal wires or ropes). It is required to drive around the borders of the property once to save the boundaries of the area that is to be mowed. I want to use the path of that drive around and draw it as a line inside the map. But is that actually the smartest way to do it? After some research I haven't found any good solutions.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350959/how-to-edit-a-map-programmatically?/) by [DesperateCookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/54142/desperatecookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-04-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a scprit that, once you run it, will save the map and add borders using something like OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2020-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DesperateCookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/54142/desperatecookie/) on 2020-05-02**:
Out solution now is like this

1. Log position inside a csv file
2. Calculate the correct pixel coordinates using the map.yaml information
3. Draw lines between the points using an pything image editing library

**Comment by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) on 2020-07-29**:
Hello! I am currently working on a project and I am facing kinda the same issue. I am trying to edit a map that I previously build using explore_lite + move_base and rtab_map packages so that I can add into it some virtual walls (no-go zones for the robot). Basically I am just trying to edit the map by drawing some lines into it given a set of coordinates, but I am having trouble in computing the correct pixel coordinates using the map.yaml information. Can you please give some information or hints related to how you did this specific thing? Thank you!

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-08-19**:
@geoporus, it is better to ask a new question regarding your specific issue.

**Comment by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on 2020-11-21**:
@DesperateCookie I am working on the same problem. Is it possible for you to share your code?
Thanks

**Comment by [ga](https://answers.ros.org/users/147454/ga/) on 2023-08-03**:
@DesperateCookie  @darshb34  hey , did you solve the problem ?